# Add/remove class from button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this [Very Lightweight Portfolio Filter for Bootstrap](https://github.com/geedmo/portfilter/blob/master/bootstrap-portfilter.js) and I want to add or remove class from the buttons being clicked.

So by default I want to set the All button with the class `btn-primary` and then when the user clicks on another button remove `btn-primary` from the All button and add the class `btn-default` to the All button and `btn-primary` to the button that was clicked.

I just can't figure out how to add this to the jquery library i'm using. Can someone help me with an example of what I should do?

Here is some code:

```
!function ($) {

  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;

  var pluginName = 'portfilter';

 /* PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
  * ============================== */

  var PortFilter = function (element) {

    this.$element = $(element);
    this.stuff    = $('[data-tag]');
    this.target   = this.$element.data('target') || '';

  };

  PortFilter.prototype.filter = function (params) {
    var items = [],
        target = this.target;
    this.stuff
        .fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function(){
            $(this).each(function(){
                if($(this).data('tag') == target || target == 'all') 
                    items.push(this);                    
            });
            $(items).show();                  
        });  
  };


 /* PLUGIN DEFINITION
  * ======================== */

  var old = $.fn[pluginName];

  $.fn[pluginName] = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data(pluginName);

      if(!data) $this.data(pluginName, (data = new PortFilter(this)));

      if (option == 'filter') data.filter();
    });
  };

  // DEFAULTS
  $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {};

  // CONSTRUCTOR CONVENTION 
  $.fn[pluginName].Constructor = PortFilter;


 /* PORTFILTER NO CONFLICT
  * ================== */

  $.fn[pluginName].noConflict = function () {
    $.fn[pluginName] = old;
    return this;
  };

 /* PORTFILTER DATA-API
  * =============== */

  $(document).on('click.portfilter.data-api', '[data-toggle^=portfilter]', function (e) {
        $(this).portfilter('filter');
        $("button").not(target).removeClass("btn-primary");
        $(target).addClass("btn-primary");
  });

}(window.jQuery);
```

This is what I added to the code above:

```
$("button").not(target).removeClass("btn-primary");
$(target).addClass("btn-primary");
```

I have tried a few other things and will be glad to share if needed.

Comment: Will you be able to create a **[mcve]** and explain?

Comment: Why the down votes to close? Isn't this a place to come for help? I will be more than happy to add an example, however I am not the best at jquery, but I will give it my best shot.

Comment: Sure. No worries. The whole text is confusing. So kindly show us a snippet or something which you have done. `:)` ^^ So does that mean, there's no code till now?

Comment: No, the link actually shows the code that handles the filter. I am trying to figure out how to add and remove classes accordingly within the filter code. I added examples above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove the btn-primary class and add btn-default class to the All button whenever a button that is not the All button gets clicked.

```
$(function () {
  $("#All").addClass("btn-primary");
  $("button").not("#All").on("click", function () {
    $("#All").addClass("btn-default).removeClass("btn-primary");
    $(this).addClass("btn-primary");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up tweaking it a bit and adding it to the portfolio code.

Comment: Not a problem! Upvotes & accepted answers are appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding this:

```
$("button").not('#'+this.id).removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
$('#'+this.id).addClass("btn-primary");
```

here:

```
$(document).on('click.portfilter.data-api', '[data-toggle^=portfilter]', function (e) {
        $(this).portfilter('filter');
  });
```

and taking this out:

```
$("button").not(target).removeClass("btn-primary");
$(target).addClass("btn-primary");
```

Comment: Yup, that looks like the generic version that I would have come up with given the full context. +1 for adapting the code to your application and not making us do that for you ;)